# Перестал работать скрипт popup'а после подгрузки данных с сервера

Tags: javascript, popup

Не так давно изучаю js и столкнулась с проблемой что перестал работать popup.
Когда карточки были вбиты вручную в html, то popup работал. Сейчас карточки создаются js'ом после прогрузки DOM-дерева. Пробовала popup оборачивать в функцию и вызывать вместе с созданием карточек, window.load. Не знаю что можно ещё сделать.

Порядок подключения скриптов:

```
<script src="search.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      start();
    });
  </script>
  <script src="popUp.js"></script>
```

Сам popup():

```
 const openPopup = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
const popupBg = document.querySelector('.pop-up--bg')
const popup = document.querySelector('.pop-up')
const closePopupBtn = document.querySelector('.pop-up--close')


console.log(openPopup)

openPopup.forEach((card) => {
        console.log(card)
        card.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            popupBg.classList.add('active')
            popup.classList.add('active')
        })
})

closePopupBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        popupBg.classList.remove('active');
        popup.classList.remove('active');
})

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (e.target === popupBg) {
            popupBg.classList.remove('active');
            popup.classList.remove('active');
        }
})
```

И создание карточек:

```
async function start() {
    let usersCardBox = document.querySelector('#cardBox');
    let usersPopup = document.querySelector('#userPopup');
    let users = await fetchUsers();

    usersCardBox.innerHTML = getUserCards(users).join('');
    usersPopup.innerHTML = getUserModals(users).join('');
}

function fetchUsers() {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'

    return fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
}

function getUserCard(user) {
    return `
        <div class="card">
          <h3 class="card--title">${user.name}</h3>
          <div class="card--phone">
            <img src="style/icon/phone.svg" width="16" height="16" alt="телефон">
            <p>${user.phone}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card--mail">
            <img src="style/icon/envelope.svg" width="16" height="16" alt="почта">
            <a href="mailto:${user.email}">${user.email}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        `;
}

function getUserModal(user) {
    return `
        <div class="pop-up--bg">
            <div class="pop-up" id="PopUp">
              <button class="pop-up--close"><img src="style/icon/popup-close.svg" width=""></button>
              <h3 class="pop-up--title">${user.name}</h3>
              <div class="pop-up--phone pop-up--flex">
                <p class="pop-up--subtitle">Телефон:</p>
                <a class="color-gray" href="tel:${user.phone}">${user.phone}</a>
              </div>
              <div class="pop-up--mail pop-up--flex">
                <p class="pop-up--subtitle">Почта:</p>
                <a class="color-gray" href="mailto:${user.email}">${user.email}</a>
              </div>
              <div class="pop-up--date pop-up--flex">
                <p class="pop-up--subtitle">Дата приема:</p>
                <p class="color-gray">${user.hire_date}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="pop-up--position pop-up--flex">
                <p class="pop-up--subtitle">Должность:</p>
                <p class="color-gray text-overflow">${user.position_name}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="pop-up--subdivision pop-up--flex">
                <p class="pop-up--subtitle">Подразделение:</p>
                <p class="color-gray text-overflow">${user.department}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="pop-up--info">
                <p class="pop-up--subtitle">Дополнительная информация:</p>
                <p class="color-gray">${user.address}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        `;
}

function getUserCards(users) {
    return  users.map(el => getUserCard(el))
}

function getUserModals(users) {
    return users.map(el => getUserModal(el))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Происходит это из-за того, что вы сначала устанавливаете обработчик событий (в данном случае click), а уже потом подгружаете данные.
Есть 2 варианта, как заставить это работать.

1. Установить обработчик нажатия на контейнер карточек. И затем уже через event смотреть куда был совершен клик. Примерно так будет выглядеть:

```js
document.querySelector('.cards-container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const target = e.target;

  if (target.closest('.cards-container') !== null) {
    const card = target.closest('.card');
    if (card !== null) {
      console.log(`Клик на ${card.innerText}`);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.cards-container {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #009f8d;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="card">Первая карточка.</div>
  <div class="card">Вторая карточка.</div>
  <div class="card">Третья карточка.</div>
</div>
```

2. Каждый раз при загрузке данных с сервера, обновлять слушатель, при помощи [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), а затем опять добавлять его.

Я бы предпочел первый вариант.

Comment: Большое спасибо!